# How to get Google Analytics's page specific data using analyticsreporting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

I am trying to fetch individual analytics reporting using google's `analyticsreporting` api v4.

I have the following pages.

https://www.example.com/uiqueId1
https://www.example.com/uiqueId2
https://www.example.com/uiqueId3
https://www.example.com/uiqueId4

Each page on load I am calling the ga set metthod. For example for uiqueId1 page,

```
ga('send', 'pageview', uiqueId1);
```

Now I am trying to get the page-specific data using
`POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet` with nodejs client.

with body

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "endDate": "yesterday",
          "startDate": "30daysAgo"
        }
      ],
      "viewId": "ga:[viewId]",
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:uniquePageviews"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which gives me `ga:uniquePageviews` for overall. How do I pass it for individual pages?

Thank you in adanvce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filters in batchGet. Read [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet?hl=ru#dimensionfilterclause) about it.

At the end you get something like this:

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "dateRanges": [...],
      "viewId": "ga:[viewId]",
      "metrics": [...],
      "dimensions": [...],
      "dimensionFilterClauses": [ 
         'filters': [
           "dimension_name": "ga:pagepath",
           "operator": "EXACT",
           "expressions": [
             `${you_page_path}`
           ],
         ],
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```